# Node js nested query with Mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

i have a problem with two mongodb queries. When i got result from first one, i asign that result to variable and perform second query for second result. Then i want to check if one array contain values from another array, if yes , then i want to remove that element from array. See example :

```
db.collection('first').find().toArray(function(err, firstResult){
    let first= [];
    let second= [];

    firstResult.forEach(function(item){
        first.push(item);
    });

    db.collection('second').find().toArray(function(err, secondResult){

        secondResult.forEach(function(item){
            second.push(item);
        });

        second.forEach(function(secondArrayElement){
            console.log( first.includes(secondArrayElement) );
        });

    });
}
```

This code gives me false result even if first array contain elements from second one. I don't know what im doing wrong.

First array: [5afb506d6a3f4029fcf670a5,5afb60924bdd992a7c4f3c84,5afb506d6a3f4029fcf670a6,5afb506d6a3f4029fcf670a7]
Second array: [5afb506d6a3f4029fcf670a7,5afb506d6a3f4029fcf670a5]

Comment: can you post your array data, for reference ?

Comment: first array contains _id of all registered users, and second contain just id's of users that have "liked": true, so my goal is to show on the client side only users that doesn't have "liked" set to true.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting only `_id`'s and `id`'s array from both the `mongodb` queries or getting array of objects which contains these `ids` along with other fields. if that's the case then it'll return false. Thats why i asked you to post array data you are getting from queries

Comment: i updated my question.Please check end of the question. I posted arrays.

Comment: Both arrays contain just id's ( but i mention _id field because it is specific because that is ObjectId )